# Faster mapping/modifying values in a large list of Python dicts?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have some code that I'm trying to speed up.  Maybe what I've got is right, but whenever I ask on StackOverflow somebody usually knows a clever little trick "Use map!", "try this lambda", or "import iteratetools" and I'm hoping somebody can help here.  This is the section of code I'm concerned with:

```
#slowest part from here....
for row_dict in json_data:
    row_dict_clean = {}
    for key, value in row_dict.items():
        value_clean = get_cleantext(value)
        row_dict_clean[key] = value_clean
    json_data_clean.append(row_dict_clean)
    total += 1
#to here...
```

The concept is pretty simple.  I have a multi-million long `list` that contains dictionaries and I need to run each `value` through a little cleaner.  Then I end up with a nice list of cleaned dictionaries.  Any clever `iterate` tool that I'm not aware of that I should be using? Here is a more complete MVE to help play with it:

```
def get_json_data_clean(json_data):
    json_data_clean = []
    total = 0
    #slowest part from here....
    for row_dict in json_data:
        row_dict_clean = {}
        for key, value in row_dict.items():
            value_clean = get_cleantext(value)
            row_dict_clean[key] = value_clean
        json_data_clean.append(row_dict_clean)
        total += 1
    #to here...
    return json_data_clean

def get_cleantext(value):
    #do complex cleaning stuffs on the string, I can't change what this does
    value = value.replace("bad", "good")
    return value

json_data = [
    {"key1":"some bad",
     "key2":"bad things",
     "key3":"extra bad"},
    {"key1":"more bad stuff",
     "key2":"wow, so much bad",
     "key3":"who dis?"},
    # a few million more dictionaries
    {"key1":"so much bad stuff",
     "key2":"the bad",
     "key3":"the more bad"},
]

json_data_clean = get_json_data_clean(json_data)
print(json_data_clean)
```

Anytime I have nested for loops a little bell rings in my head, there is probably a better way to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you done any profiling? From looking at your example, it seems like `get_cleantext` should take up 99%+ of your execution time, yet you haven't provided the code inside that function. If `get_cleantext` takes up more than 90% of runtime, it doesn't matter how fast the rest of the code is.  For us to be able to properly analyze the code, we need to see the code in its proper context.

Comment: Do you know how to measure timing performance? And also, do you need speed? A lot of the best SO answers I've seen on this topic do timing comparisons. If you are doing JSON, you can do some neat encoding/decoding tricks to apply cleaning - look for functions like `json.loads(response.text, object_hook=json_numpy_obj_hook)`

Comment: Ah, excellent point.  I shall profile it, completely forgot about that!  My caffeine hasn't kicked in yet :)  Should I delete this question until I profile it?

Comment: Exactly, both - if this isn't the rate-limiting step and it only needs to be run once, then why bother? :)))

Comment: @sniperd is a good starting point - am sure you can see how to apply it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909658/json-encoder-and-decoder-for-complex-numpy-arrays/27948073#27948073

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: For the record: I am reapplying @Peilonrayz' close vote at their request because of the close-vote invalidation cycle earlier. I don't personally consider the question off-topic and am considering opening a meta-question about it

Comment: What's funny is I originally posted this on StackOverflow and got feedback that it was better suited for Code Review :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start putting all this in a function:

```
def foo(row_dict):
       row_dict_clean = {}
        for key, value in row_dict.items():
            value_clean = get_cleantext(value)
            row_dict_clean[key] = value_clean
        return row_dict_clean
```

and then puting everything inside a comprehension list:

```
json_data_clean = [foo(row_dict) for row_dict in json_data]
total = len(json_data_clean)
```

I tried to create the dictionary with a comprehension, but it does not seem to give so much improvement. Maybe the dataset is too small, but in case you want to try, substitute the second loop for:

```
row_dict_clean = {key: get_cleantext(value) for key, value in row_dict.items()}
```

Maybe there are more performances that can be done with the dictionaries itself, but this for sure will save you good time.

Comment: Excellent, this gives me some good ideas.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. `total` is never used, remove it.
2. You can inline `get_cleantext`, or post your actual code.
3. you can just use a list and dictionary comprehension to reduce the amount of noise in your code.

```
def clean_json_data(json_data):
    return [
        {
            key: value.replace('bad', 'good')
            for key, value in row.items()
        }
        for row in json_data
    ]
```